# how to customize map.merge with executor.submit()

Tags: java, spring, java-8

Objective :
  i wanted to include the thread part of executor which mapped with key . whenever i try to insert the same key , it should validate the current future object state , if it's completed then it should take up thread part of executor .

Observed Behavior : 
i have a map with key type as string and value type as Future<> whenever map undergoes for loop and finds the the same key it should evaluate the condition instead executor get's submitted and then goes to evaluate the condition , can anyone help me on achieving with merge functionality , i'm aware of using map.put() traditional way and it works . looking for how to use this part map.merge

Sample Code :

```
    Map <String,Future<SampleThread>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    String s[] = {"A","A","A","A"};
    for (String i :s){
        map.merge(i,executor.submit(new SampleThread(i,true)),    
                (v1,v2) -> test(v1,v2));
    }

   private static Future<SampleThread> test(Future<SampleThread> v1,Future<SampleThread> v2) {
        if (v1.isDone() || v1.isCancelled()) {
            return v2;
        }
        return v1;
    }

    public class SampleThread implements Callable{

        private String msg ;
        private boolean flag = false ;

        public SampleThread(String msg,boolean flag) {
            this.msg=msg;
            this.flag=flag;
        }

        public SampleThread call() {
            //Singleton.getInstance().submit(msg,flag);
            System.out.println(this.msg);
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return this;

        }
```

Comment: You might be looking for putIfAbsent. also,  it is very cheap to look into the map for a key and check its state, so you might want to just do that.

Comment: i believe merge was brought to eliminate the use of computeIfPresent and moreover time complexity wise o(1) i believe and assume an example if k,v pair is of type <Integer,String> let's assume during the iteration we encounter with same key and we have written an remapping function to handle it gets into remapping function and validates the condition and updates the map while it's not the case if i had executor.submit as value ~ some how i believe before remapping function getting called it inserts into executor.submit

Comment: Perhaps if you create the thread v2 inside the test function it will do what you are aiming to do. The way it is it creates the thread for comparison and that is not a good use of resources.